# MongoDB : missing ; before statement with for instruction

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hi I know there are some questions about this but I didn't find any solutions for my problem.
My script works fine without the for loop but when it's in I've got an SyntaxError : Missing ; before statement...

Here is my script :

```
for (var i = 100; i < 301; ++i) {
    use F000 + i;
    var collections = db.getCollectionNames();
    collections.forEach(function(coll) {
        var c = db.getCollection(coll);
        c.remove({ date : { $lt : ISODate("2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z") }});
    });
}
```

Thanks helping me finding the solution.

EDIT : The line who raise the Error is : 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:32

Comment: what line raises the error? `use F000 + i;`, isn't it?

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for the quick answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to switch the database with this bit of code (`use F000 + i;` in your example):

```
conn = new Mongo()
db = conn.getDB("dbname")
```

or if you're already connected you can use

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('dbname')
```

`use` is just a shell helper and doesn't work in scripts.

Here is some extra reading too - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo